# Change selection WPF combobox by variable

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I'm using a combobox to show categories a user can choose.

[image]

All those items have the id as the SelectedValuePath so I can easly get those when the user makes a selection.

```
<ComboBox Grid.Column ="1" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="200" Name="cboCategorieen" ItemsSource="{Binding}" DisplayMemberPath="naam" SelectedValuePath="id" />
```

But how can I change the selection of the combobox when I have the id of the chosen selection (SelectedValuePath)?
This code doesn't do anything and just keeps selecting the first one.

```
cboCategorieen.SelectedValuePath = Convert.ToString(artikelWijzigen.categorie);
```

To conclude:
How can I change the selection of the combobox to the one matching the id?

Comment: Where do you bind the ItemsSource to the combobox? post the code

Comment: Using my webservice, I get a list of all the items. wsWebshopMRentals = new WebshopMRentals();
            cboCategorieen.DataContext = wsWebshopMRentals.GetAlleSubcategorieen();
            cboCategorieen.SelectedIndex = 0;

Comment: are you following MVVM?

Comment: No, I only fetch the data when the window is opened

Comment: Try to set selected value like cboCategorieen.SelectedValue = selectedCategoryId;

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. Guess I'm going to ask my teacher in a few days and post the solution here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to follow MVVM, Still the answer for your question would be Say if you have a ItemsSource like this,

```
ObservableCollection<YourComboBoxClass> wsWebshopMRentals;
```

You can set the selectedItem of combobox like this,

```
cboCategorieen.SelectedValue = wsWebshopMRentals.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == YourID).naam;
```